# Import error using gaepytz (pytz in gae)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pytz

I am trying to use pytz on gae and found gaepytz. But, I get an import error when importing it and I think it is because I am not placing the original pytz and gaepytz side by side correctly in my app dir. (assuming I need to!)

```
./appdir/pytz [ original pytz folder, including zoneinfo subdir]

./appdir/gaepytz
```

in a `foo.py` file in the `appdir`, I have:

from `gaepytz.gae` `import pytz`

gives me an error from `gae.py` importing zipfile, which in turn fails importing _io module.

```
ImportError: No module named _io
```

What am I missing? Thx

On experimenting more, I find that I get this error even without gaepytz ie.
import zipfile 
in a helloworld app gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vatsanp/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 4144, in _HandleRequest
    self._Dispatch(dispatcher, self.rfile, outfile, env_dict)
  File "/home/vatsanp/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 4049, in _Dispatch
    base_env_dict=env_dict)
  File "/home/vatsanp/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 616, in Dispatch
    base_env_dict=base_env_dict)
  File "/home/vatsanp/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 3120, in Dispatch
    self._module_dict)
  File "/home/vatsanp/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 3024, in ExecuteCGI
    reset_modules = exec_script(handler_path, cgi_path, hook)
  File "/home/vatsanp/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2887, in ExecuteOrImportScript
    exec module_code in script_module.__dict__
  File "/home/vatsanp/google_appengine/helloworld/helloworld.py", line 8, in <module>
    import zipfile
  File "/home/vatsanp/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vatsanp/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2503, in load_module
    return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
  File "/home/vatsanp/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vatsanp/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2375, in FindAndLoadModule
    description)
  File "/home/vatsanp/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vatsanp/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2318, in LoadModuleRestricted
    description)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 6, in <module>
    import io
  File "/home/vatsanp/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vatsanp/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2503, in load_module
    return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
  File "/home/vatsanp/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vatsanp/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2375, in FindAndLoadModule
    description)
  File "/home/vatsanp/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vatsanp/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2318, in LoadModuleRestricted
    description)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 60, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: No module named _io
```

Comment: Please include the complete stacktrace, rather than your interpretation of it.

Comment: BTW, 'mytz' works fine. it is only with gaepytz that I get this error. still don't know why, but unblocked at this point.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if you try to run the dev_appserver with Python 2.7, which doesn't currently work. Use Python 2.5 instead. If you're developing against the Python 2.7 runtime, remember that the dev_appserver doesn't yet have support for it, and you'll have to deploy in order to test your code.

Comment: Thanks much. This was the real issue!